# Adaptive payments through PayPal

Tags: paypal

Are adaptive payments through PayPal possible?

If a website, let’s call it `example.com` is selling services, like fiverr.com for ex. and:

- person A is selling video services on `example.com`
- person B is buying A video services from `example.com`

I need to know if somehow me (as `example.com`) can I control the payment, in order to pay person A if he did his job correctly, or to not pay him because he didn't made his the job as he said for the person B

Ideally it will be to pay person A, after person B is satisfy with person A job, and to avoid paying direct person A when person B order/paid services in that moment.

Comment: We are not PayPal support!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it is possible if you are the primary receiver. In your use case person B will be the buyer and person A and somewebsite.com will be the receivers with somewebsite.com controlling the payments. Refer this link for more information https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-delayedChainedPayment-curl-etc/

Comment: delay is the same think with blocking the payment?

Comment: no, they are not the same. In delaying payments you are deferring the payments until the buyer is satisfied, while in blocking payments you are blacklisting the buyer.

Comment: anybody know from where I can control delay or deferring payments? in order to activate the payment or to keep it in delay mode?